# Load a view controller only for first time user opens app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to add some code to my iOS app that opens a view controller only the first time the user downloads and opens the app - after that it should not load this view controller. Any other time, it should open to a different view controller on launch.

Answer (score 2):

In your `AppDelgate`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, assign your `self.viewController` as launching screen.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"yourCondition"])
{
     //launch your first time view
     self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"singletimeview" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
   //launch your default view
   self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"yourCondition"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use NSUserDefaults.Create a key and set value for it if its first launch or not.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"firstLaunch"]){
        //key exists and this is not the first time app launch
    }
else{
        //your first time app launch
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        UIViewController *firstAppLaunchVC = ...;
    }
```